# After adding a managed property in Query Text the Refiners disappear in Build your query tab

Tags: managed-property, content-search-web-part, refiner

I have the following query: `path:{Site.URL}  ContentTypeId:0x0102* clsStartDate>{Today-1}` and when I use it in the Query Text of Content Search Web Part, the Refiners in the refiners tab disappear.

The moment I remove `clsStartDate>{Today-1}`, they return back.

If I have selected a refiner in Refiners tab, and when I insert the managed property in my query: `path:{Site.URL}  ContentTypeId:0x0102* clsStartDate>{Today-1}`, I get the result as show in the image below with a strange number, instead of `Event` content type.

Why am I getting this strange behavior?

[image]